# Short 2D Animation Video software for HTML5 display

Tags: html, animation, svg

I plan to make a very short 2D animation video (about 1mn to 2mn maximum) that can be viewed in a web browser.

My first guess was to use [Tupi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupi_%28software%29) which generate OGG and MPEG files that I can embed in a static HTML5.
But I would rather like to have a canvas with my animation to be rendered in realtime.

So what I would need is to export my animation to SVG files (at least 24-30 SVG per second of animation) so I can display them one after the other on my canvas.

Is there a software that allow me to do that ?
I'm open to any idea !

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Animate CC (flash) can do exactly this - render vector animation on HTML5 canvas with javascript, but it's 10€/month or so. IMO it's worth the money if you have some income (and if not, internet is your friend) as it has some very nice features regarding animation.

But I see nothing wrong with embedding video or gif if all you want is to watch the animation. Then any software is good if it can export video (ToonBoom Harmony ($$$), Animate ($), Photoshop ($), Synfig, Krita, even 3D package like blender - whatever floats your boat).

Answer (score 1):

I love Express Animate: http://www.nchsoftware.com/animation/

It can output a Mp4 video, but also export a Html5 version modifying the obects using JavaScript, so you only have the original assets and a JavaSvript file.

I think it is not using canvas, only JavaScript.